# Save image from url with curl PHP

Tags: php, image, curl

I need to save an image from a url using CURL and save it to a folder on my server.  I've been battling with this code to no avail.  Ideally I'd like to grab the image and save it as "photo1" or something.  Help!

```
    function GetImageFromUrl($link)

    {

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$link);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;

    }

    $sourcecode = GetImageFromUrl($iticon);

    $savefile = fopen(' /img/uploads/' . $iconfilename, 'w');
    fwrite($savefile, $sourcecode);
    fclose($savefile);
```

Answer (score 128, accepted):

try this:

```
function grab_image($url,$saveto){
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($saveto)){
        unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

and ensure that in php.ini allow_url_fopen is enable

Comment: Thanks!  I'll keep trying at this thing, and see if that works.

Comment: Keep in mind well coded websites will look for a user-agent.  Every browser, tablet or phone will always has a user-agent! If you are still unable to get an image, most likely because of user-agent detection, add this... `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'MyImage Collector +http://www.yourdomainname/mybot.html');`  or spoof a real one `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');`

Comment: Is there any file size limitation while saving image like this? Does the file upload limitation in PHP config affect this?

Comment: "ensure that in php.ini allow_url_fopen is enable" do we need this setting?

Comment: You should really add a warning for that 'unlink' function - it's super dangerous if you're not careful with it. Noobs beware!

Answer (score 35):

**Option #1**

Instead of picking the binary/raw data into a variable and then writing, you can use `CURLOPT_FILE` option to directly show a file to the curl for the downloading.

Here is the function:

```
// takes URL of image and Path for the image as parameter
function download_image1($image_url, $image_file){
    $fp = fopen ($image_file, 'w+');              // open file handle

    $ch = curl_init($image_url);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // enable if you want
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);          // output to file
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);      // some large value to allow curl to run for a long time
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);   // Enable this line to see debug prints
    curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);                              // closing curl handle
    fclose($fp);                                  // closing file handle
}
```

And here is how you should call it:

```
// test the download function
download_image1("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/10773ae6687b55736e171c038b4228d2", "local_image1.jpg");
```

**Option #2**

Now, **If you want to download a very large file**, that case above function may not become handy. You can use the below function this time for handling a big file. Also, you can print progress(in `%` or in any other format) if you want. Below function is implemented using a `callback` function that writes a chunk of data in to the file in to the progress of downloading.

```
// takes URL of image and Path for the image as parameter
function download_image2($image_url){
    $ch = curl_init($image_url);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // enable if you want
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);      // some large value to allow curl to run for a long time
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, "curl_callback");
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);   // Enable this line to see debug prints
    curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);                              // closing curl handle
}

/** callback function for curl */
function curl_callback($ch, $bytes){
    global $fp;
    $len = fwrite($fp, $bytes);
    // if you want, you can use any progress printing here
    return $len;
}
```

And here is how to call this function:

```
// test the download function
$image_file = "local_image2.jpg";
$fp = fopen ($image_file, 'w+');              // open file handle
download_image2("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/10773ae6687b55736e171c038b4228d2");
fclose($fp);                                  // closing file handle
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to download an image **from https**:

```
$output_filename = 'output.png';
$host = "https://.../source.png"; // <-- Source image url (FIX THIS)
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // <-- don't forget this
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); // <-- and this
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$fp = fopen($output_filename, 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $result);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Your code solved my **The requested URL returned error: 503 Service Unavailable** problem. Thank you sir and have a nice day.

Comment: Do not do this unless you want to be vulnerable to man in the middle attacks, which could replace the image content with a malicious script.

Answer (score 3):

Improved version of Komang answer (add referer and user agent, check if you can write the file), return true if it's ok, false if there is an error :

```
public function downloadImage($url,$filename){
    if(file_exists($filename)){
        @unlink($filename);
    }
    $fp = fopen($filename,'w');
    if($fp){
        $ch = curl_init ($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = parse_url($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $result['scheme'].'://'.$result['host']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0');
        $raw=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        if($raw){
            fwrite($fp, $raw);
        }
        fclose($fp);
        if(!$raw){
            @unlink($filename);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` reads the entire file to a php variable first. It's slower and can break on large files. Pass the file pointer with `CURLOPT_FILE`, instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is easiest implement.

```
function downloadFile($url, $path)
{
    $newfname = $path;
    $file = fopen($url, 'rb');
    if ($file) {
        $newf = fopen($newfname, 'wb');
        if ($newf) {
            while (!feof($file)) {
                fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8), 1024 * 8);
            }
        }
    }
    if ($file) {
        fclose($file);
    }
    if ($newf) {
        fclose($newf);
    }
}
```