# file_get_contents gives me failed to open stream

Tags: php, arrays, url, download

I have simple CI (CodeIgniter) code. what I want to do is: when I enter the pictures path to textarea, php downloaded each picture to my server and gave them filenames, but I have these errors:

```
Message: file_get_contents(http://geosmiley.ge/Upload/Product/42/1.jpg ) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Message: file_get_contents(http://geosmiley.ge/Upload/Product/42/2.jpg ) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument
```

Here is my CI code:

```
$image = explode("\n", $_POST['images']);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($image); $i++){
    if (substr($image[$i], 0, strlen($this->host) - 1) != $this->host){
        file_put_contents('images/'.$title_url.'_'.$i.'.jpg', file_get_contents($image[$i]));
        $image[$i] = $this->host.'/images/'.$title_url.'_'.$i.'.jpg';                                
    }
}
$poster = $image[0];
$images = implode("\n", $image);
```

***What it does is simply downloads last file and for first and second files gives me that error***

and please don't give me other advice like using cURL of fopen. I think that it is correct way because php downloads LAST FILE successfully. Please help me to solve my problem

Comment: Is "allow_fopen_url" turned on? http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: "Tandu" I will NOT allow fopen, for security purpose

Comment: then you can't use urls with `file_get_contents`.  It also requires that setting to be turned on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save image from url with curl PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476212/save-image-from-url-with-curl-php)

Comment: please look at my modified code, that can help you to help me, plzz

Comment: The error message looks like you have a trailing whitespace ( ) after the path. Try removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Why the problem happened but here is the code that fixed it, thanks to "NikiC" who found out that witespace " " was the problem, I fixed it.

***This Code doesn't work***

```
$image = explode("\n", $_POST['images']);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($image); $i++){
    if (substr($image[$i], 0, strlen($this->host) - 1) != $this->host){
        file_put_contents('images/'.$title_url.'_'.$i.'.jpg', file_get_contents($image[$i]));
        $image[$i] = $this->host.'/images/'.$title_url.'_'.$i.'.jpg';                                
    }
}
$poster = $image[0];
$images = implode("\n", $image);
```

***This is working code***

```
$image = explode("\n", $_POST['images']);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($image); $i++){
    if (substr($image[$i], 0, strlen($this->host) - 1) != $this->host){
        if ($i < count($image)-1){
            $kk = substr($image[$i], 0, strlen($image[$i]) - 1);
        } else {
            $kk = $image[$i];
        }
        if ($this->download($kk, 'images/'.$title_url.'_'.$i.'.jpg')){
            $image[$i] = $this->host.'/images/'.$title_url.'_'.$i.'.jpg';
        }else{
            echo($image[$i]);
        }
    }
}
//****************************************************
    public function download($url, $path){
        if (file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($url))){return TRUE;}else{return FALSE;}
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen
>   wrappers have been enabled.

You will either need to set `allow_url_fopen` to true or use [cURL](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead.

Comment: I would like to know WHY MY CODE DOESN'T WORK? What mistake I have done

Comment: You need to check your php.ini for the `allow_url_fopen` setting. If this isn't set properly, `file_get_contents` will fail.

Comment: @user939421 as webbiedave mentioned it might be disabled on your server side, check your phpinfo or use cURL extention

Comment: please look at my modified code, that can help you to help me, plzz

Comment: Do as webbiedave has stated. Make a PHP script with only `<?=phpinfo();?>` run that, and check if `allow_url_fopen` is set.

Comment: it is not set on, and I can't set it on too, it is disabled by server whis is not going to enable it. But most important is that php downloads third picture completly but has problems with first two pictures

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your URL in quotes; make it a string

Comment: looks like you're right, but I'm curious, since he gives the url with a variable file_get_contents($image[$i]), why the need of quotes?

Comment: I tried file_get_contents('"'.$image[$i].'"'); but not worked

Comment: please look at my modified code, that can help you to help me, plzz