# How can I extract an image from a url using php, jquery and ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, post

I am hoping to create a link submission page similar to that of Reddit's where I can show the thumbnail of a given URL without reloading the page.  What would be the best way to do this and are there any examples?

Comment: There was a good article on this but I can't find it. Here's something related http://www.99points.info/2010/07/facebook-like-extracting-url-data-with-jquery-ajax-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You'll need to use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).
2. To download images with cURL, you can modify [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6476232/491494) to suit your needs.
3. You'll need to come up with an algorithm that will choose the most "interesting" image. This is because a lot of pages will have multiple images. If you're lazy or if it's not a major issue, you could simply choose the first image in the document.
4. To "parse" HTML and make sense of it (with PHP), you can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).
5. Once you download the image, you should crop it, save the cropped version and then get rid of the original (FAR better than simply saving and re-sizing the original on the fly).

Using cURL and DOMDocument together, you should be able to put something together.