# Executing curl image download from browser load

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I have a php curl script which downloads an image from a specified url.

[Save image from url with curl PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476212/save-image-from-url-with-curl-php)

```
function grabImage($url,  $saveto){
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($saveto)){
        unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
}

grabImage("www.example.com/image/2.png", "/var/www/site/images/image_2.png")
```

When a person visits my site an image from my server is downloaded however if the image is unavailable it will use curl to download it from my suppliers server, I would rather all images are downloaded from my server directly as I would not want to put any strain on my suppliers server.

The script works fine when running it in ssh e.g. `/usr/bin/php /var/www/site/image_s.php` but when loading it in a browser it does not download the image. 
e.g. `www.example.com/image_s.php`

What do I need to do to make sure that a browser load is enough to download the image?

Comment: Does it print any errors or warnings?

Comment: @Martin no errors have been printed out, when I look at my log file I also see no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more searching on the web and it turns out that you need to change folder permissions, by default the public can not write into a folder.

in linux you can change permission by doing the following

`chmod 666 /var/www/site/folder_name`

Comment: Sorry i mean 777, but I'm worried about the security implications

Comment: that's why I added `775`, which is a safer choice.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a web server permissions error, when you run it on the console, you are running under the user you logged in as.  this is not the same as the user that serves the website content (it could be 'nobody')

Comment: yes I relies that which is why I added the permission tag, but I've given it all read, write & execution permissions with no luck

Comment: you'll need to check that the permissions you've added are for the right user