# Download images from specific array of urls with php

Tags: php, arrays

I need to download some images from a specific array of urls, something like:

```
<?php
  $images = array('http://url1.com/img1.png','http://url1.com/img2.png'); 
   // download this images from this paths
```

I saw some scripts here but don't get them exactly on how can i link them to this array.

The expected output would be: When i run the script to download those images from that array to a specific folder from my server: `home/user/public_html/images`. It's much appreciated anyone who helps me, i am trying but can't make the connections, currently a rookie.

Comment: `foreach()` loop, then what ever code to process one at a time

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476212/save-image-from-url-with-curl-php

Comment: can we see your script?

Comment: @Dagon more specifically?

Comment: @MrHunter It;s not duplicate refers to a specific thing (Download from SPECIFIC array). I searched a lot before posting the question.

Comment: you said you had code to do one url, so all you need is to put that inside a foreach loop

Comment: @AlirezaFallah That's the problem, i saw lots of scripts here but don't really no exactly how to connect to this, because all of them are about how to take from a single path of a known absolute path of a remote server or different then what i need.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe.

```
$images = array('http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/214RgVjsvTL.jpg','http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/515pMJlul8L.jpg'); 

foreach($images as $name=>$image) {

    //get image
    $imageData = file_get_contents($image); //$image variable is the url from your array

    $name = explode("/", $image);

    $handle = fopen("images/".$name[5],"x+");     

    fwrite($handle,$imageData);

    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: I get `file_get_contents(http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/515pMJlul8L.jpg ) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`

Comment: http://www.testingcom.tk/test.php here is the testing and the contents: http://codepad.org/e7zp7UdC. Hope it's not like a forbidden error from amazon.

Comment: @user3140607 You have a newline at the end of the URLS in your code. Remove those and try again.

Comment: I can see that it makes some empty files `$handle = fopen("images/image".$count.".png","x+");` the fact is that i need the exact name of the image from the specified url. Example: the url is http://amazon.com/imagexyz.png to get downloaded with that name: imagexyz.png, so no need for a contor.

Comment: It downloads them perfectly excepting the name, how can i get the exact name, instead of image1...

Comment: I see, so this is the only way :( Would have been great to detect after 5 slashes to copy the name directly.

Comment: @user3140607 I updated my answer to use `explode`. Hope that helps! :)http://us1.php.net/explode

Comment: `$name = explode('/', $image); $name = end($name);` or `$name = basename($image);` works without relying on the number of path segments being constant.