# how to get image from curl

Tags: php, curl

My script works well except for the url in the code. I always get a 404. Of course I can get the image from browser. Could anybody help me fix this?
PS:Actually, I could use method int "questions/6476212" to get the image file. But when trying to open the image file, the content in the file is a 404 page not the image.

```
$url = 'https://spthumbnails.5min.com/10368406/518420256_c_570_411.jpg';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.1 Safari/537.11');
$res = curl_exec($ch);
$rescode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($ch) ;
echo $res;"
```

Comment: Does the server use cookies to verify requests at all?

Comment: Have you tried adding : 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
because JPG file transfer should be done in binary mode?

Comment: I have no idea about that:(  How to check for cookie?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476212/save-image-from-url-with-curl-php link.

Comment: binarytransfer added,still got the 404:(

Comment: @GiantRobot : the page don't set cookies.  maybe you can look in your error log file....

Comment: Actually, I could use "questions/6476212" to get the image file. But when trying to open the image file, the content in the file is a 404 page not the image.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your script is correctly written. I have tried and works fine, but you need to set image headers in order to let navigator show the image.

Example:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

$url = 'https://images.nga.gov/en/web_images/constable.jpg';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.1 Safari/537.11');
$res = curl_exec($ch);
$rescode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($ch) ;
echo $res;
```

But please note your image url is down, that's why you are getting 404 error.

-- Edit Y2023 --

If you want the script to be prepared for 302 code (redirect) you will need to add the following headers

CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION = true
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS = 10 // This is not mandatory (-1 By default).

Regards

Comment: and if the url does a 302 redirect to another image url. what do we need to add to this?

Comment: @Shaho I think it would require the flag CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION = true and CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS higher than 0

the code would be similar excepting for those flags