# Can i Show Image without extension

Tags: php, jquery, css, image

Let me know if i can make url of image like this 
http://placehold.it/1000/1000
other then this
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/sXAwqoJ-WUA/maxresdefault.jpg

In short, i want to change image link (https://i.ytimg.com/vi/sXAwqoJ-WUA/maxresdefault.jpg) to my site directory (mysite.com/images/one)

Edit: This is not duplicate of other question because i want to do this when the image is not on my server.

Comment: store the file on your server and use apache's `mod_rewrite`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use images without extension in <img>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110384/can-i-use-images-without-extension-in-img)

Comment: but this can be possible when image on my server. I want to do this with youtube thumb url for - https://fbthumbtube.com where people can use large thumb but image not in my server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this for that you have to create an html file and in 'index.html' you can insert images into the image tag.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title> images </title>

</head>

<body>

<img src="http://placehold.it/1000/1000 " style="max-width: 100%">

</body>

</html>
```

file loction 
**mysite.com/images/one/index.html** 
and run your link mysite.com/images/one

Answer (score 0):

First things first: you need to own the `placehold.it` domain.

Then...

1. Redirect `http://placehold.it/1000/1000` to be handled by a php script. For example in your placehold.it server add the following rule to the .htaccess file:

   `Redirect /1000/1000 /myscript.php`
2. Let myscript.php to get the image from the remote-server and serve it (check this thread: [how to get image from curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702489/how-to-get-image-from-curl))

   - (optional) in order to minimize curl requests to the remote server (and optimize performance) you can save the image (once) and then serve the saved copy (whenever requested)
3. Write the html ...

   `<img src="http://placehold.it/1000/1000">`

Comment: This would be more clear if you weren't referring specifically to placehold.it.