# is there a way to display image retrieved using php curl in the main page content

Tags: php, html, laravel, web, curl

i have two servers and i want to display image from my admin server to the client server.
i have tried the following:

```
<img class="pop_image" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $pop_rslt['link_to'] ?>'" src="<?php echo imgCurl('odealsdev.in/crons2/fetch_image_by_name.php?name=exit_pop_up/'.$pop_rslt["pop_up_image"]);?>">
```

this is my client server. And i want to display the image from this location.the fetch_image_by_name.php looks like this

```
if(isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['name'])){
unset($file_headers);
$file_headers = @get_headers('https://sdev.in/administratie/images/' .$HTTP_GET_VARS['name']);
if($file_headers[0] != 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'){
echo 'https://sdev.ekibo.nl/administratie/images/' .$HTTP_GET_VARS['name'];
}

}
```

and my curl function looks like this

```
function imgCurl($url){
  $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

echo $raw;
}
```

but the main problem i mean the error i get is src='unknown'.
pls someone help me to achieve this displaying images from my another server. i had gone through many stack results but non of them helped me to solve this since all are showing to download and display in separate page
If i give the header type in curl as image/jpg then my whole page becomes a image type.please someone help me fix this

Comment: could just base64 inline it (bad practice, slow & memory & bandwidth-hungry & cache-unfriendly, but it works)

Comment: @hanshenrik when i use like this as u have just said my server won't allow ..it's creates security issue. that's y i choose to use the curl but i want to just ping the server so that i can get the src and use it well in live

Comment: isn't this very simple ? `<img src="https://sdev.ekibo.nl/administratie/images/img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">`

Comment: @Dlk really it is but it will not work in my server.but it does work in my development server

Comment: This will answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27702621/12232340

Comment: @Dlk i used this link before but my website becomes image type. it has become like the image not as web page since the header type is defined image so it acts like this

Comment: @SabujHassan could u pls help

Comment: @Walf  could u pls help