# How to get large images from EBay listings with wget

Tags: curl, wget

Is there a way to get only the large images that are inside the listings on EBay? For example I want to get only the images from this EBay page:

http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xstamps+1972.TRS0&_nkw=stamps+1972&_sacat=0

The problem is that I don't know how to use wget (or anything else) in that way so it can only grab the large photos from inside the listings like this one:

http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxMjQz/z/JwkAAOSwdsFUL9F2/$_57.JPG

Comment: I have posted an answer about downloading a very large file using php. You can check my answer there from `Option#2` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476212/save-image-from-url-with-curl-php

Comment: Thank you for your answer SabujHassan. I actually meant large in terms of dimensions of the image and not the size in terms of Kilobytes/Megabytes. Unless of course you mean something else and I misunderstood it