# Laravel 5 get image and save from youtube

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, youtube-api

OK, I have been struggling for about 2 days on this. 
I can get an image from youtube like this,

```
$filename = $video_id . '.jpg';
$youtube_thumb_url = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/". $video_id . "/maxresdefault.jpg"; 
$imagedata = file_get_contents($youtube_thumb_url) ;
```

this is where I am stuck, how do I save this back to a .jpg file?
I tried this,

```
$imagedata->move('uploads', $filename );
```

But that did not work, because $imagedata is a string.

I thought of trying to convert $imagedata, but I cant figure out what the format of is.

Help Please.
Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using curl to get images from uri, then save the image

[Save image from url with curl PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476212/save-image-from-url-with-curl-php)

Answer (score 0):

`file_put_contents()`: Writes a string or array to a file.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php