# Not downloading file of regular expression url

Tags: php, curl

It's gives 404 Not Found While downloading file from url.
i want to downloads file from url links.

i am tried with curl in PHP.

```php
$output_filename = "text.jpg";

$imageUrl = "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZjZhYTkyMjgtNjFkZi00NDAyLTk5ZDgtMDYwZTBkYTI1ODllXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTc5OTMwOTQ@._V1_.jpg";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $imageUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.xcontest.org");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result); // prints the contents of the collected file before writing..


// the following lines write the contents to a file in the same directory (provided permissions etc)
$fp = fopen($output_filename, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $result);
fclose($fp);
```

When i runs script it returns me 404 not found warning for file not found.
i also try to found solution from internet but not getting exact result.
i think it gives warning due to downloading file from  **regular expression**  url link.

file is exist while paste image url in browser as show below image.

[image]

Comment: It says file not found because the file you are trying to download is not there.

Comment: yes, i try to download file from url using curl in php. post code which i was try for it.

Comment: Try putting the url image link in your browser, it doesn't exist.

Comment: No, file is exist, Please copy image link($imageUrl) and past it in browser address bar and press enter, displaying image.

Comment: [No image, 404 not found.](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZjZhYTkyMjgtNjFkZi00NDAyLTk5ZDgtMDYwZTBkYTI1ODllXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTc5OTMwOTQ@._V1_.jpg)

Comment: this will help you :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476212/save-image-from-url-with-curl-php

Comment: I am able to see image:- http://prntscr.com/p1irgz

Comment: Thank You @AnantSing but downloads file is empty 0kb size, allow_url_fopen is already on in php.ini file

Comment: @l'L'l what client are you using? whatever client it is, your client is not using compression, see my answer below

Comment: @hanshenrik: I was using `Safari`, good answer, I didn’t think of that +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZjZhYTkyMjgtNjFkZi00NDAyLTk5ZDgtMDYwZTBkYTI1ODllXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTc5OTMwOTQ@._V1_.jpg
```

will show a http 404 error unless you attempt to use transfer compression (like `gzip` or `deflate`)

that's probably a bug in their image cache server, and someone should send a bugreport to the media-amazon.com sysadmin. in any case, by default curl does not attempt to use transfer compression, you have to explicitly enable it, and to enable it just set CURLOPT_ENCODING to emptystring, eg

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
```

that tells curl to attempt transfer compression, and you should get the image (but again, this is a *bug in the server*, someone should let them know so they can fix it!)